# http request from website to cloud function in php

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-functions

I want to trigger a HTTP cloud function from my php website to update a firestore record.

```
  $url = 'https://us-central1-myprojectid.cloudfunctions.net/updateOrderStatus';
        $client = new Client();
        $response = $client->post($url, [
            'form_params' => [
                'orderId' => '2',
                'newStatus' => 3,
            ]
        ]);
```

Here is my cloud function

```
exports.updateOrderStatus = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  console.log("Inside updateOrderStatus function's onCall");
  console.log(data);
  }
);
```

But I am getting below error in cloud function

```
Request has incorrect Content-Type. application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and below exception in my laravel screen

```
Client error: `POST https://us-central1-myprojectid.cloudfunctions.net/updateOrderStatus` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
```

Comment: The HTTP POST method supports several data encodings for the HTTP body. Which one does the endpoint that you are calling require? Review articles like this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST and this one: https://reqbin.com/Article/HttpPost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Laravel 7+, use the [`Http` facade](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/http-client)...

So, your code should be:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

Http::post(
    'https://us-central1-myprojectid.cloudfunctions.net/updateOrderStatus',
    [
        'form_params' => [
            'orderId' => '2',
            'newStatus' => 3,
        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: getting error in my cloud function ``` Request body is missing data.``` and ``` Error: Invalid request, unable to process. at entryFromArgs (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger/index.js:130:19)```